# "text-align: center;" dompdf laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, dompdf, laravel-5.5

i am creating a simple system that send automatically generated rapports to some people via e-mail. These rapports are generated with dompdf in laravel, and consist of tables.

In these tables i want to align an icon in the center of the cell, but when i use "text-align: center;", it doesn't center in the pdf but it does on the webpage.

I am using laravel 5.5 and the [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) dompdf package for laravel.

EDIT:

As Html i have table cells that look like this:

```
<td class="status empty">
    <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</td>
```

And my css for the cells look like this:

```
table tr td.status {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Better use internal CSS or inline CSS to process such PDF operations. We cant just predict your scenario good if you can provide some code references.

Comment: You're right, i've added some code that might be helpfull